# df is not included in build/tmp/hosttools

Tags: yocto, openembedded, linux-disk-free

I am using bitbake to build a recipe.

One recipe shows it needs **df**.

I checked

```
build/tmp/hosttools
```

df is not there, but I can manually copy df from /bin/df

How to config yocto to let it include **df** tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying a binary manually may not work.
You need to include df to HOSTTOOLS in bitbake.conf

For example: **oe-core/meta/conf/bitbake.conf** 
under the topic **Build utility info**.

HOSTTOOLS += "
    [ ar as awk basename bash bzip2 cat chgrp chmod chown date **df** du echo

do it like this. It will work.

Comment: Do I need to modify it before 'source oe-init-build-env' ?

Comment: You can modify after 'source oe-init-build-env' also , but just do a clean build of your recipe. "bitbake recipe-name -c clean" then "bitbake recipe-name"